# How to check for any files with FileExists(String) method

Tags: vb.net, file, file-exists

I'm trying to automate a document handling process, and I need to check if there are any files inside a certain folder. The process itself removes the files from the folder once it finishes, so I need it to loop back and check if there are any files left.

So far I've been using a sample file like this:

```
File.Exists("C:\Users\gcaor\Desktop\OC\150.pdf")
```

150.pdf is the sample file it's searching for, but is there a way to search for any file at all? So that it returns true if there is a file in the folder and false if there isn't

Comment: `A = Dir("C:\*.*"): If A = "" Then msgbox "No Files"`

Comment: Please don't tag your question with both vb.net and vb6 tags. vb.net and vb6 are different languages with different syntax.

Comment: Could you just remove the entire folder, and avoid the check for files?

Comment: Sorry about that! I'll remember not to do that next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-6.0) + `Any`:

```
Dim anyFileExist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any()
```

This is using standard .NET methods and also stops at the first file found.